# How to make a custom pod library depending on Firebase pods?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I have a very simple swift 3 pod library depending on Firebase pod. It has been created with `pod lib create` and the only line of code in the library is `import Firebase`. Still, Firebase does not seem to be detected.

```
-> FoobarLib (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ~/FoobarLib/Classes/Foobar.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Firebase'
```

I suppose my .podspec file is not properly configured. I have tried a simple pod dependency with `s.dependency Firebase` and I have tried to [embed the Firebase frameworks](https://github.com/azmeuk/FoobarLib/tree/master/FoobarLib/Frameworks/Firebase) in my library. I have played with `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`, `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS`, but I never got something working.

My sample library [is hosted on github](https://github.com/azmeuk/FoobarLib) and the full error log is available [on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/azmeuk/FoobarLib). Feel free to clone it, and test `pod lib lint` and `pod install --project-directory=Example`.

I saw this related [cocoapods bug report](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5368) involving cocoapods guys and firebase guys, but there is no working example in it.

What should I put in my .podspec file so:

- `pod install --project-directory=Example` succeeds, and produces a valid XCode project. i.e. I can open it, compile it without further configuration.
- `pod lib lint` succeeds, optionally

Comment: Did you create the project in xcode? If so, what kind of project did you choose?

Comment: The lib has not been created with XCode but with `pod lib create`

Answer (score 4):

Even if you manage to get `pod lib lint` to pass, you'll run into issues integrating Firebase as a dependency of a dependency because it's currently vended as a static library. [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS) works around this by distributing binaries instead of having CocoaPods build from source, but it's not without its own caveats (i.e. people who use FirebaseUI cannot also use another library that depends on Firebase and correctly resolve the version of Firebase that should be used). The issue you linked discusses this in more detail.

If you would really like to distribute a library that wraps Firebase through CocoaPods, you should follow the same approach, though it's worth noting that `pod lib lint` fails for FirebaseUI even though it ships anyway.

CocoaPods will soon (as of Oct 2017) add a rule that allows for static frameworks to be built on top of other static frameworks, including closed-source ones. This will make it much easier to build objc libs on top of other closed static objc libs, but Swift static library support is still in the works.

Comment: I am good with those caveats. I also tried to distribute the firebase binaries (they are hosted in my repository), but I could not manage to produce something that actually worked.

Comment: @azmeuk i am having the same issue. Did you get any working solution ?